# How can I correctly perform a JavaScript function from a span element?

Tags: javascript, html

In a file named **Script.js** that is declared in my page by

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/Script.js"></script>
```

I find this simple `nomeApp()` function:

```
function nomeApp() {
    document.writeln("<span class='bluebold14'>"+VERSIONE_APPLICAZIONE+"</span>");
    ScriviSoc (VALORE_SOCIETA);
}
```

that writes an HTML tag into my page (into the specific place from where it is called).

In my page I have a span like this:

```
<span id="myPage"></span>
```

And from here I have to perform the previous `nomeApp()` that writes inside it.

What do I have to do to perform this function from this span?

Comment: To be clear, you want `<span class='bluebold14'>` to appear inside your `<span id="myPage"></span>`?

Comment: If you're downvoting valid answers, it's only polite to explain why the answer doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simply don't use `document.writeln()` use `document.createElement()` instead, here's the code you need:

```
function nomeApp() {
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    newSpan.className = 'bluebold14';
    newSpan.innerText = VERSIONE_APPLICAZIONE;
    document.getElementById("myPage").appendChild(newSpan);
    ScriviSoc (VALORE_SOCIETA);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform that function by clicking on element - `onClick="functionName()"`:

```
<span onClick="nomeApp()">CLICK ME</span>
```

If you want to perform that function immediately without any user interaction, than you must call that function (let's say at the end of page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     nomeApp();
</script>
```

---

Read about auto-start functions (anonymous functions), events, jQuery.